# Random patches that do not satisfy recoloring condition get recolored

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a model where agents represent a team of individuals working on a group project. Setup generates slider percentage of patches with workload of 1, and agents with skills that vary from 0 to 1. When an agent encounters a patch with a workload != 0, they are asked to recolor the patch, and the color they choose is dependent on their skill.

Intended action happens - employees recolor patches according to their skill, but the problem is that they randomly recolor patches without workload. Sum of patches with "quality_of_work" 1, 2, or 3 should equal 'count whereiswork', but I get most of the patches filled with color even when 5 or 10% of patches are setup with work. Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

```
to go
  if all? patches [ workload = 0 ] [ stop ]
  ask employees [move]
  ask leaders [move]
  ask employees-on patches with [workload != 0] [recolor]
  tick
end

to recolor
  ask employees with [skills < 0.3] [
    set pcolor sky
    set workload 0
    set quality_of_work 1
  ]
  ask employees with [skills > 0.3 and skills <= 0.6] [
    set pcolor violet
    set workload 0
    set quality_of_work 2
  ]
  ask employees with [skills > 0.61 and skills <= 1] [
    set pcolor red
    set workload 0
    set quality_of_work 3
  ]
  
  set whereiswork patches with [workload > 0]
  set sloppy count patches with [quality_of_work = 1 ]
  set mediocre count patches with [quality_of_work = 2]
  set great count patches with [quality_of_work = 3]
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what behaviour you are expecting here. You ask the employees to colour patches based on the employee's skill (not on the workload of the patch) and have them move around. That will colour lots of patches.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought that “ask employees-on patches with [workload != 0] [recolor]” would function as a prerequisite condition for “recolor” function to occur, only coloring if the patch they are on has workload greater than 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your restriction does not apply in the way you think it does. You have:

```
to go
  ...
  ask employees-on patches with [workload != 0] [recolor]
end

to recolor
  ask employees with [skills < 0.3] [
    set pcolor sky
    set workload 0
    set quality_of_work 1
  ]
  ...
end
```

The `ask` in the go procedure applies to all the employees on patches with 0 workload. Say you have two such employees in this tick (call them A and B). The `ask` instructs them EACH to run the recolor procedure. Imagine that A goes first (note that `ask` runs through the agentset in a random order each time). So employee A jumps to the recolor procedure and then finds every employee with a skill < 0.3 and tells those employees to colour their patch and so on. Then employee B comes along and tells them all to do it again. If you have N employees who satisfy the condition, then the patches are being coloured N times each tick.

So your recolor procedure should be written from the perspective of an individual employee turtle. In that case, it is more like "if I have skill < 0.3 then colour my patch sky". That would look like:

```
to recolor
  if skills < 0.3
  [ set pcolor sky
    set workload 0
    set quality_of_work 1
  ]
  ...
end
```

This nested ask problem is very common so I usually recommend that NetLogo beginners keep the asking and the instructions within the same procedure. Something like:

```
to go
  ...
  recolor
end

to recolor
  ask employees-on patches with [workload != 0] 
  [ if skills < 0.3
    [ set pcolor sky
      set workload 0
      set quality_of_work 1
    ]
    ...
  ]
  ...
end
```

Alternatively, you can use tricks to remind yourself that the recolor procedure is a turtle procedure. You could comment it (which is what is done in the NetLogo model library) or you could name the procedure in a way that would remind you (such as recolor-my-patch).

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed and fast response! Appreciate your expertise and kindness :)